# AsyncTask or Progress bar without pressing Button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to use asynctask or progress bar in this program.Can i use Asynctask or Progress Bar in this program without pressing any button?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
      // Getting JSON Array
      user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
      JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
      // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
      String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
      String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
      String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
      //Importing TextView
      final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
      final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
      final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
      //Set JSON Data in TextView
      uid.setText(id);
      name1.setText(name);
      email1.setText(email);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you looked at the documentation and/or searched for sample code on the internet?

Comment: If I understand you, You want parse the JSON and when it finish put the information at the textviews? If I correct tell me, I think I've the solution.

Comment: @ Lacrirra 
Yes Brother you are right.i want to parse the JSON which views the data in textView.

Answer (score 0):

***`What you are doing`***::
*You are performing a `network request` in the `UI-thread` (i:e- onCreate)*

---

***`What you should do`***::

- The tasks that take longer time(`eg: network request`) to execute must be done on the
  `separate thread`
- For this use Async-Task

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* CALL THE ASYNC TASK*/
        new DownloadTask().execute();
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog; 

    /* Start the progress in onPreExecute */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); 
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
    }

    /* Do the background task in do in background*/
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

       /** ADD your code here **/

        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
              // Getting JSON Array
              user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
              JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
              // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
              String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
              String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
              String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
              //Importing TextView
              final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
              final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
              final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
              //Set JSON Data in TextView
              uid.setText(id);
              name1.setText(name);
              email1.setText(email);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 
        return Void;
    }

    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's common for many new programmers to think that displaying a ProgressBar is a very simple task. It's usually not as easy as it "seems it should be."

That said, you will need to run all network calls (like getting data from a URL) in a background task/thread. And if you want to display a progress bar, you will need to reference it on the UI thread when you are done.

Many people find the convenience of AsyncTask with it's "postExecute" method does this just fine. I'm adding some other keywords here to help you find an answer appropriate to your problem because I rarely use AsyncTask. And when I first started doing it, seemed harder than it should have been (even though I was wrong about that).